# Horizontal Scrolling of Latex Environment

Tags: packages

I just want to know that there is a latex code or special packages which enables latex environment to be scrolled horizontally by tapping/moving it to left-right side, in which some huge websites like Wikipedia used that to avoid bad display of long equations (in math). 
Please help me. I searched in the google with appropriate key words, but found no leads.

Comment: It would be easier to understand what you wanted if you added [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) to show what you are doing: without code that exhibits your problem we have to guess what you are doing. It sounds a little like you may be using mathjax on a web page, in which case TeX.SE is probably not the right place to ask this question. If you add a MWE it will be much clearer what you are trying to and easier to help you.

Comment: I think you cannot put scrollable boxes inside a pdf, but I might be wrong.

Comment: you can make any page as wide as you like, but scrolling is a feature of the pdf viewer being used not of the document

Comment: @Johannes_B You can. Don't know about horizontal scrolling, but certainly vertical scrolling is possible with `hyperref`.